# File Directory - Replace Backward Slash "\" with Forward Slash "/"

Tags: javascript, html, directory, directory-structure

On a daily basis, I save my web pages files on a public drive. I then have to send a direct link of the html file to the client.

To do so, I tend to manually convert all the backslashes "\" from the folder directory into forward slashes "/" as well as adding "http://" at the beggining.

Example:

> From
>   `\\Public\Drive\PageLocation\`
>   To
>   `http://Public/Drive/PageLocation/index.html`

I've started using the find and replace option, but I feel like it would be much better if there was some sort of code that converts these paths in an input field.

Here's a quick visual of what I have in mind:

```css
*{font-family:sans-serif;}

p{
  font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<p>Folder Directory to URL </p>
<input type="text" placeholder="\\Public\Drive\PageLocation\">
<input type="submit" value="Convert">
<br>

<span>Result: http://Public/Drive/PageLocation/index.html</span>
<br/><br/>

<p>URL to Folder Directory </p>
<input type="text" placeholder="http://Public/Drive/PageLocation/index.html">
<input type="submit" value="Convert">
<br>

<span>Result: \\Public\Drive\PageLocation\</span>
```

I've tried figuring out JavaScript RegExp, but I didn't find much luck making it functional. It seems like it can only read double backslashes and ignores singles:

```js
var FolderDirectory = "\\Public\Drive\PageLocation";
var URLConvert = FolderDirectory.replace(/\\/g, "/");
alert(URLConvert);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there such thing as a hotkey that converts slashes?
What do you guys use?
Is there an alternative way that I could convert slashes locally?
What would you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is perfect, the problem is the string you are changing. In javascript, a backslash (\) is used to escape a char.

> The backslash (\) escape character turns special characters into string characters... 
>  [Javascript Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Here's a working example of what you want to do:

```js
document.getElementById('input').onkeyup = function() {
  //when someone types in the input
  var v = this.value; //input's value
  if (v[0] === '\\') {
    //text entered is a url
    //                                add 'http:'        replace \ with /
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'http:' + v.replace(/\\/g, '/');
  } else {
    //text entered is a path
    //                                            remove http or https     replace / with \
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = v.replace(/https?:/g, '').replace(/\//g, '\\');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=text placeholder="enter file path or url" id=input>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Works perfectly :) I was surprised that you've made possible the conversion to adapt itself from the input value of url and path.

Comment: Yeah, no problem!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem already is your start string. The backslashes where interpreted as escape characters. So they dont exist in the string. But if you want to input the path in a HTML form, the string does already contain the backslashes in the correct way. See here my short example.

```js
    function convert(){
        var src_url = document.getElementById("path").value;
        var converted_url = src_url.replace("\\\\", "http://").replace(/\\/g, "/");
        alert(converted_url);
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="path" value="\\Public\Drive\PageLocation\">
<input type="button" value="convert" onclick="convert()">
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for sharing :)